# Is there a way to ssh in windows 8.1 pro without 3rd party tools?

Tags: ssh, windows-8.1

Well, the title says it all, but I'll give some background:

I am trying to configure a NAS to host a GIT repository as described here:
http://blog.osdev.org/git/2014/02/13/using-git-on-a-synology-nas.html

> Next, ssh into the NAS device as the root user.

Which leaves me blank because I never heard of SSH before :-)

I tried powershell, but I couldn't find a command to start such a session.

Comment: Why are you against using a ssh client?

Comment: @Ramhound: Well not really in particular. But I assumed it would be something basic like telnet. In general I prefer the functionality given by the OS, if it's there. Especially if I am not going to use it on a daily basis.

Comment: @Ramhound: but assuming there isn't a OS provided client, can you recommend one?

Comment: No;  Do your research on which clients you should use.  The version of Powershell that comes with Windows 10 has SSH support in the future by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound: so, if there isn't one in win 8.1 post it as answer so I can mark it as such ;-)

Comment: I don't post answers that basically amount to indicating "no".

Comment: cygwin's openssh is all command line, has ssh_config and sshd_config  just like *nix so better than putty in many ways and it has a server too not just a client. (putty is client only)  winsshd is a good server.. gives you access to `C:\>` rather than `$`

Comment: -1  Your question loses value because of your willingness to accept wrong answers. It's better off posting your own answer and accepting that. (if you're able to post a correct answer.. which shouldn't be too hard if the answer is basically no windows doesn't have an ssh client).

Comment: By the way, as to this odd meaningless thing you wrote " I assumed it would be something basic like telnet."  You were talking about an SSH client. Telnet is not an ssh client.  Windows does have a telnet client you can enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Windows 8 running on your NAS? Or do you just want to connect to your NAS via SSH? As [@Ramhound said in his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/960438/is-there-a-way-to-ssh-in-windows-8-1-pro-without-3rd-party-tools/960443#comment1312484_960438), you can find [SSH support in Windows Powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/06/03/looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh.aspx) with Windows 10.

A commonly used ssh client for all windows family is [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Comment: Powershell doesn't have the feature yet.  I was careful about the way I worded my comment.

Comment: I don't have win 8 on the NAS. I needed to SSH to the NAS. As @Ramhound stated; I couldn't find any SSH client in powershell or anywhere else in the OS. I'll settle for PuTTY for now.

Comment: AT Ramhound, you say you were careful the way you worded your comment, but you wrote "The version of Powershell that comes with Windows 10 has SSH support in the future by the way" <-- It isn't even clear what that sentence you wrote means.  Like you're saying the specific version of powershell that comes with Windows 10 is going to suddenly start supporting ssh in the future.  Maybe you mean a future version of powershell will support SSH. Tho There do seem 2b people doing ssh things in powershell , see a comment here posted 3 years ago of it done https://pwrshell.net/module-ssh-powershell/

Comment: Also i've heard that powershell supports anything .NET has, so maybe it can be done already like the commenter at that link has, just MS may be doing something native / not so third party.